# How to populate <Hyperlink> NavigateUri property from <MultiBinding>?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this code

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="">
  <Run>
     <Run.Text>
         <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}">
              <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxHostData" />
              <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxWebSiteDataName" />
              <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxDataServicesName" />
          </MultiBinding>
     </Run.Text>
  </Run>
</Hyperlink>
```

How I can use `<MultiBinding>` to populate `NavigateUri=""`?

Is it possible at all?

---

Thanks to **@ThomasLevesque** !

SOLUTION:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <c:StringToUriConverter x:Key="stringToUriConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Hyperlink.NavigateUri>
        <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="" Converter="{StaticResource uriConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxHostData" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxWebSiteDataName" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxDataServicesName" />
        </MultiBinding>
</Hyperlink.NavigateUri>
```

C#

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(String), typeof(Uri))]
public class UriConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Uri result;
            string input = String.Join(string.Empty, values);

            Uri.TryCreate(input,  UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out result);
            return result;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but not with `StringFormat` (which works only for properties of type `String`). You need to use a converter instead.

```
<Hyperlink.NavigateUri>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource uriConverter}">
        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxHostData" />
        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxWebSiteDataName" />
        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxDataServicesName" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Hyperlink.NavigateUri>
```

```cs
public class UriConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string uriString = String.Join(string.Empty, values);
        return new Uri(uriString);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically MultiValueConverter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx